# Android phone's USB host support the TM4C123G as a device

Tags: android, usb

Can Android phone's USB host support the TM4C123G as a device ,TM4C123G has been loaded the program which is a example named as usb_dev_bulk provided by tiva.

Who can help me?  and give me some ways to achive this.

Comment: You should give more information about the problem you are experiencing, you cannot expect that anyone knows what a TM4C124G is. For example, what is the Product ID, Vendor Id, Class Id, Subclass ID of your device?

Comment: Sorry，It is my fault,Now,My android phone is used in usb host mode,TM4C124G is a board produced by TEXAS INSTRUMENTS company,more things turn to "http://www.ti.com.cn/tool/cn/dk-tm4c123g",My problem is my android phone can not recognize the TM4C123G board when i connect the board to my phone by a usb line

Comment: Can you give some information from the descriptor, like product id, ventor id, class id, subclass id?

Answer (score 0):

Your Android device needs to support USB OTG (On The Go), you need an OTG host cable and then you need to write an app that conforms to the Android USB Host APIs at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

I would suggest trying out the excellent example app by @devunwired at https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples  Specifically, try out the UsbMonitor app which shows if a USB device is detected, along with its interfaces and endpoints.

Comment: Thank you very much，I have written a program which is used to detected the device attached,but bow,when i attach the TM4C123G to it,my app can not detect the device,this is my problem!     could you give me some tips????

Comment: Verify your cabling (specifically that it is grounding the OTG ID pin) with some other device.  On many phones, plugging in a mouse through a working OTG adapter will get you a mouse cursor.